# What is the probability that two socks of the same color are selected from a drawer containing $2$ blue, $4$ red, and $2$ yellow socks?

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:
[image]

I can not solve this question so I am asking what exactly in the probability theory that I must revise so I could solve it, could anyone give me advice please?

Comment: You just need standard approach. It means $$P=\frac{\text{suitable cases}}{\text{total cases}}$$

Comment: Go through all of the cases.  Consider blue socks, what is the chance the chance you pull a blue sock on the first pull and a blue sock on the second pull?  Now consider red, and finally yellow.

Comment: You can use Bayes' Law, but as others are commenting it's easier to do it directly.

Comment: For discrete probability, you should begin by revising combinatorics.  In particular, you need to understand the Multiplication Principle, Addition Principle, permutations, and combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not so much a question on probability as it is on combinatorics.
One usually solves this kind of question as follows:

$\quad(1)$: Calculate the **number of possible outcomes**.

In our case, we're drawing $2$ socks out of a drawer with $8$ socks, so the number is $\binom{8}{2}=28$.
If you are unfamiliar with the notation $\binom{n}k$, you should look into binomial coefficients and their combinatorial interpretation -- in short, that's the number of ways to choose $k$ out of $n$ objects.

$\quad(2)$: Calculate the **number of success cases**.

There are three cases here:

$\qquad(2.1)$: Two blue socks. Well, there's a single possibility here.

$\qquad(2.2)$: Two red socks. We can choose $2$ out of $4$ red socks, so that's $\binom42$ possibilities.

$\qquad(2.3)$: Two yellow socks. Once again, there's a single possibility here.

The total number of success cases is hence $1+\binom42+1=1+6+1=8$.

$\quad(3)$: Calculate the probability, which is simply

$$\frac{\text{Number of success cases}}{\text{Number of posssible outcomes}}=\frac{8}{28}\simeq 28.57\%$$

Answer (score 1):

There are three colours.   You are to draw two socks, and may as well place them in front of you.   For each of the colours, what is the probability that the sock on your left is that colour and, *given that*, that the sock on the right is so too?

$$\def\blank{{\underline{\quad}}} \blank\times\blank~~+~~\blank\times\blank~~+~~\blank\times\blank $$

Fill in the blanks.